# What are the best practices for object props in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue Component that is a form for creating (or editing) a patient. It contains a lot of information: birthname, firstname, date of birth, birth place, gender, etc.

What are the best practices in terms of maintainability, reactivity and performance to pass those information?

Is this recommended to pass each information item as a prop?

```js
<patient-form
  :firstname.sync="patient.firstname"
  :lastname.sync="patient.lastname"
  :birthdate.sync="patient.birthdate"
  ... />
```

Or more recommended to use an object Patient with all the information?

```js
<patient-form :patient="patient" @update="updatePatient"/>
```

Comment: use a store, vuex/pinia, props are for component options not data, if you pass patient as-is its ok but you'll get linting and vue warnings if you mutate props, so would lead you onto copying incoming data to a component model then emit out, which is messier then using a store

Comment: Using a store for this kind of data exchange is overkill... It's a data exchange between parent and child components. It has to be resolved with props and events

Comment: sure but it comes with some crevets, like reactivity is shallow, meaning if you pass only parent and you copy the prop into a local model within the child, then parent updates patient.birthdate it wont be reactive in the child because its copied on mounted etc, additionally your need watch child properties in the prop to update the model because components are cached.

Comment: Yes we used a lot stores... But we have problem with them. Reactivity when we don't want, need to update the data in store always, etc... It's too heavy for a simple use case like this (IMO). Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is totally depends on the use case of `<patient-form>` component and the data you are using in this component.

- If you have multiple reference of `<patient-form>` in a parent component. `i.e` in case of edit the parent information against each parent record. In this case, I will suggest to get the real time parent information from a database through an API call in the child component itself.

  Hence, As per my understanding the best approach would be, pass the parent id as a `prop` in the `<patient-form>` component and then get the real time updated data by calling an API based on patient id and bind the response in the template. Then on successful edit, you can post the data and emit the `success` event to parent.

  In parent component **:**

  ```
   <patient-form :patientid="patient.id" @update="isUpdateSuccess"/>
  ```

  In child component **:**

  ```
   mounted() {
     // get parent data based on the `patientid` parameter and bind that in the template.
   }

   methods: {
     onUpdate(id) {
       // post the updated data with the help of an API call.
       // emit the success event on parent else show the error in the child itself.
     }
  }
  ```
- But if still you already have the `patient` data in your parent component and you want to pass that in the `<patient-form>` component, Then your second solution is better than the first one. Go for that.

Comment: In facts, the patient-form is just one of many other forms... For example an operation-form with a patient-form and other forms... Passing props one by one allows us to have a bigger control on reactivity knowing what have been modified. But in term of maintenability it's heavy... So you don't see any problem in passing a whole object to a child component

Comment: @MuyBien Ideally data updation should be happen at a backend so that everyone can get the real time data. From frontend point of view, if you will use `ref()` for whole object, It will be reactive if you will update any of its properties from a child component.